# Check if element with class of 'X' has a rel of 'N'

Tags: jquery, css, class, if-statement, rel

If you have an element with a certain class, for example `class="selected"` and need to see if it has a certain rel value, how would one do that?

In basic logic:

```
If('.selected' has 'rel=6'){
//action
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this;

```
If($(".selected").attr('rel') == '6'){ alert("ok"); }
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest form is:

```
if ( $('.selected[rel=6]').length ){
    //object found
}
```

Comment: Your answer is better, as it will work with multiple elements as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [**.is**](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
var $selected = $('.selected');
if ($selected.is('[rel=6]')) { ... }
```

... or [**.filter**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $selected = $('.selected'),
    $rel6     = $selected.filter('[rel=6]');
```

... jQuery methods, depending on what you actually need.